# Adding a cronjob for a different user from a script?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a script that is executed by the user "www-data" that requires adding a couple of cronjob that run under the user "test".

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "* * * * * test /usr/local/bin/test.sh" > /etc/cron.d/myjob
```

Fails because obviously www-data has no permissions to write to that folder and I doubt changing the folder permissions is a good idea.

```
#!/bin/bash
(crontab -u test -l ; echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/test.sh") | crontab -u test -
```

Gives `must be privileged to use -u` despite adding `www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab` to visudo.

It must be noted its not possible to ssh into the server to manually add the job. I'm trying to do this through a web based interface that allows user to select some values, and then run a script on the box to set it up.

How can I have "www-data" create a cronjob for the user "test"?

Comment: Make sure requiretty is not set

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `sudo` privileges you added to have any effect at all, you have to actually *use* `sudo`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
( crontab -u test -l;
  echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/test.sh") |
sudo crontab -u test -
# ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you cannot do this without superuser access because this is a security violation.
Since we're most probably talking about shared hosting, probably there is no way to configure sudo rules or create files inside /etc/cron.d/, but there may be some UI to configure cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

@tripleee

Thanks for putting me on the right path. Putting sudo infront of both commands fixed the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
( sudo crontab -u test -l;
  echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/test.sh") |
sudo crontab -u test -
```